# change type of from to string[]

Tags: android

```
String[] from = new string[]{ NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE };
```

this is my statement which is showing an error stating that "change type of `from` to `string[]`".

I couldn't resolve it , what is this error for ? and how to get rid of it ?

Comment: The "S" must be in uppercase `String[] from = new String[]{ NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE };`

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `string` in lowercase, you should write it like this:

```
String[] from = new String[]{ NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE };
```

Since Java takes `String` and `string` as two different classes